# E6 arrow functions reduce an array of object to single object

Tags: arrays, json, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I've an array like:

```
a=[{'test':1,'test2':'2'},{'test':3,'test2':'4'}]
```

I'm trying to reduce this array to one object

**Expected output**

```
{1:2,3:4}
```

I've tried:

```
let newObj = a.reduce((pre,curr)=>Object.assign({},{curr.test:curr.test2}))//unexpected token at .
let newObj = a.reduce((pre,curr)=>Object.assign({},{curr['test']:curr['test2']}))//unexpected token at [
```

**P.S**: I have already achieved what I'm trying by not using arrow functions, I want to know why the above methods doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as

```
a.reduce(
    (acc, {test: key, test2: value}) => Object.assign({}, acc, {[key]: value}),
    {}
)
```

So what you're doing here is - destructure the every element to `key` and `value`, then combine the current accumulator with the new object that consists of just those `key-value` pair.

What you were doing wrong: you cannot use expressions as object keys as-is, but you must wrap those in the square brackets.

So this `{[curr.test]: curr.test2}` would work.

Comment: Wow!! never thought it was as simple as that . Haven't found any docs on how to use use expressions as obj keys...Thanks a ton

Comment: @NishanthMatha https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015 (look for "Computed property names")